# repaint gridView in loop

Tags: java

I have 1 `gridview`..
And here my code:

```
 for (int i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       // View_score.setAlpha(0);
        final int[] key = {1};
        System.out.println("" + i + ": " + path.get(i));
        wall.get(path.get(i)).setiWall(-8);
        Thread closeActivity = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("aa");
                    key[0] =0;
                    // gv.callOnClick();
                    // Do some stuff
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
            }
        });
        closeActivity.start();
        while (key[0]==1){
        }
        closeActivity.interrupt();
        adapter_playing.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //gv.invalidateViews();
        gv.setAdapter(adapter_playing);
    }
```

//
`gridview` will change after `wall.get(path.get(i)).setiWall(-8);`
and `sleep 0.1s`.
I want after sleep `gridview` repaint but my problem: until end of loop my `gridview` start repaint.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU6hg.png)

Thanks everyone.

actually i'm  creating `Animation`  when my ball move like this game: [enter link description here](http://choigame.biz/games/line-98/)
So each loop i change 1 image in item `gridview` and `sleep` with purpose to create `Animation` but no. `gridview` just repaint when end loop. Like:

I want:

```
   1.when `start` : On `gridview` will [][][][]
    2.And after 0.1s  : On `gridview` will [.][][][]
    3.after 0.1s : On `gridview` will [.][.][][]
    4.after 0.1s : On `gridview` will [.][.][.][]
    5.after 0.1s  end loop : On `gridview` will [.][.][.][.]
```

But now:

```
1.when `start` : On `gridview` will [][][][]
2.And after 0.1s  : On `gridview` will [][][][]
3.after 0.1s : On `gridview` will [][][][]
4.after 0.1s : On `gridview` will [][][][]
5.after 0.1s  end loop : On `gridview` will [.][.][.][.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the closeActivity thread. This thread may be sleeping but your function exists on a separate thread and therefore the sleep is not halting the code you want.

```
for (int i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   // View_score.setAlpha(0);
    final int[] key = {1};
    System.out.println("" + i + ": " + path.get(i));
    wall.get(path.get(i)).setiWall(-8);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("aa");
                key[0] =0;
                // gv.callOnClick();
                // Do some stuff
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
    adapter_playing.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //gv.invalidateViews();
    gv.setAdapter(adapter_playing);
}
```

This may or may not solve your issue. Due to your question's lack of clarity, I am not entirely understanding what your issue is.  Essentially, if you remove the new thread that you make, and simply invoke your sleep function within the active thread, it will wait before setting key[0]=0

Comment: Thanks for help. I edited my question and you can help me resolve ?